# Windows 8.1 - System process uses 1 core up to ~90% constantly

Tags: windows-8.1, drivers, cpu, cpu-usage

[Asus N550JV](https://www.asus.com/Notebooks_Ultrabooks/N550JV/) comes with Windows 8 installed. I prefer 8.1 so I installed Windows 8.1 on my machine. Downloaded all the specified drivers on [Asus Support Page](https://www.asus.com/Notebooks_Ultrabooks/N550JV/HelpDesk_Download/), not to mention my whole system is up to date.

I've seen a few questions about this problem. [This one in particular](https://superuser.com/questions/527401/high-cpu-usage-by-the-system-process) looked pretty similar to my problem, which leads to a faulty driver. So, here's my scenario:

[image]

I have created a new power plan called gaming, which is simply the "High Performance" power plan. The problem with that "High Performance" power plan is that either power cable plugged in or not, the system uses Core #1 constantly at a high percentage as seen on the right corner of the screenshot.

On the other hand, when Balanced power plan is selected, once I plug out the power cable, the green core (Core #1) falls down to normal while some other core rises up to around 50%. When I plug power back in, the green core goes up high again.

I downloaded the process explorer as suggested [in this answer](https://superuser.com/a/527557/279815) and when I clicked on properties section of the System process on process explorer, and identified "**ACPI.sys+0x62a0**" as the culprit.

Okay, we know the suspect now but how can I fix this issue? What am I supposed to do since the system is up to date?

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/14859013#14859013

Comment: ACPI relates to power management, if that helps at all.

Answer (score 0):

Well 5% overall non-idle time isn't all that bad, but the fact that it's not allowing your CPU to switch states is a problem (the fact that ACPI.sys is eating a bit of CPU shows that it's either trying and failing to control the CPU for some reason, or intentionally eating up cycles so that it keeps the frequency high).

More likely is that most of your processes are running on a single core for efficiency's sake. If all but one core is basically idling, it will be more efficiently utilizing the processor overall, despite the fact that you told it "I don't want the processor to be idle".

So the main question is: Do you want your PC to idle or not? The High Performance profile basically says to the computer: "I don't want to be idle, be at top frequency whenever possible, unless nothing at all is going on".

Personally, I don't thing this is a problem at all, since it's doing exactly as you told it to.
Under the Balanced profile, when unplugged all cores are expected to be 50% or less if possible. Since not all processes can run on one core comfortably at that speed, they get put on other cores (why you see the others rise in CPU and basically balance out on battery). When you plug it back in, all systems are go, we can go fast again, and the processes move back to the first core again (now that we're basically allowed to go fast again).